# Images are not loading on initially. When we manually hitting image url then showing the image

Tags: wordpress, image, caching, server, browser-cache

All the images are available on the page if we inspect the page and manually hit the image url then it is showing the image but when I am loading the page, images are not loading. Here is the url http://lifestyledesigninternational.com/home/

When we manually hit the image url in browser and then reload the page, it is showing that image on the page but not the other images.

I have tried by storing the images in the browser cache but it didn't worked. Unfortunately I dont know the server detail of the website, I just have the cpanel.

Comment: Did you check the difference between http://...... and https://.............?

Comment: You are having the issue of http and https. Convert your website in https only or in http. It will automatically resolved your problem

Comment: @AkshayShah can you see the images on your side?

Comment: Yes with changing the url of image src i can see.

Comment: By changing I can also see the images, can you see the images directly when you loads the page?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88A7x.jpg)Add http: before the starting of each image src i think it will work fine after this .

like http://Your_image_url

You have not add http: before So images is not showing in your site

Comment: can you see all images at your end?

Comment: can you pls share screenshot of your browser

Comment: so give me your email to send the screen short

Comment: i can't send it now because right now i am in my office.